# SignalR: Managing OnDisconnect() with multiple hubs

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

I have a SignalR application which manages users and connections, User / Room, with a database.  I followed the following article (under **Permanent, external storage** -> **Database**)

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections

As someone logs in, I insert their entry into a Room table, and remove it as they leave.

I now have two hubs, "Chat" and "Game".

Lets say for example UserA into both Chat and Game hub.  I create 2 entries into both a Chat table and Game table.  However, if UserA does a 'non-graceful' close of a single hub (ie. close tab), I am not able to pick which room/hub UserA disconnected from. (OnDisconnect does not allow me to capture these details).  This forces me to remove all occurrences of UserA across all tables he is found in on my database

Now how is it possible for me to know which hub UserA exited from so that I may only remove his entry for that particular room. (e.g. UserA is in both **Game Room** and **Chat Room**.  He closes the **Game Room** window.  Application needs to only remove his entry from **Game Room** table.)

Any input, suggestions is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In every method that is called in your SignalR `Hub` you have access to the unique `ConnectionId` through `this.Context.ConnectionId`. You should link this id to the user.

Once in the `OnDisconnected` handler, use that `ConnectionId` to know which user has left.

And according to [this article](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server):

> The connection ID is a GUID that is assigned by SignalR (you can't specify the value in your own code). There is one connection ID for each connection, and the same connection ID is used by all Hubs if you have multiple Hubs in your application.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I was considering using ConnectionIds, the article linked is the same as the one I had put in the OP above.  Could I just verify one thing though.

Does that mean a User may have multiple ConnectionId's? One for Game Room and another for Chat Room?

Comment: Okay, I think there is some misunderstanding. 

"Once in the OnDisconnected handler, use that ConnectionId to know which user has left.".  I am already able to pick out which user has left.  I want to now know which hub the single user has left.  Looking at the documentation, It seems like all both the "Game Room" and "Chat Room" hub will be sharing the same ConnectionId.  Therefore I can't use that to distinguish which room they have left.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you get into `GameRoomHub.OnDisconnected`, then the user left the Game-room, not the Chat-room, right?

Comment: Yes, so maybe a way I could manage these connections is when creating a room, specify the "Type" of room.(e.g. Chat) in one column.  That way when he disconnects from a "Chat" Hub.  I'll search for an occurrence of the user in Rooms of Type "Chat"? .

Comment: Either that or separate tables, that's really up to you! Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

What I do is when the user connects, in the `OnConnected` method I simply add their `ConnectionId` to a key in the database that is similar to:

```
UserId:HubName:ConnectionId
```

The `HubName` part I get through reflection: `Type.GetType().Name`

I use this key to add in the database when the user connects and remove it from the same database when `OnDisconnected` gets called.

Now, keep in mind that if the server fails at some point, the `OnDisconnected` method doesn't get called, so you are left in the database with some `ConnectionId`'s that you think belong to a user, but they actually no longer do.

Every time the server starts, I would search the database for `ConnnectionId`'s and verify if they are actually active (most probably not) and delete them.

Hope this helps. Best of luck!